# Creating a very simple Dynamic Google Script Web App

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, dynamic, web-applications

OK I'm stuck at the beginning of setting up a dynamic stand-alone google script. I can't get the button to make any dynamic change to the html.  I would figure that clicking the button will call the google script code function and would make a change to the resulting Index.html.  What am I missing?

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
         .setTitle('DynamicTest');
}

function DoSomething() {
  var obj = document.getElementById("status");
  alert("kachow");
  obj.innerText = "It's magic!";    
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
  <br />
  <div id="status">Static</div>
  <br />
  <script>
  document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  google.script.run.DoSomething();
  });
  </script>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

Thanks!

---

---

---

**Update Solution:** Thanks @Tanaike for the solution! Here is the full code which also adds an pre-processing message as well as a post-processing message that is displayed after the google script app finishes the called function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
  <br />
  <div id="status">Static</div>
  <br />
  <script>
  document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function() { 
    var obj = document.getElementById('status');
    obj.innerText = 'Processing. Please wait...';
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(value => {
      var obj = document.getElementById("status");
      obj.innerText = value;
    }).DoSomething();
  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
         .setTitle('DynamicTest');
}

function DoSomething() {
  return "It's magic!";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, it seems that `DoSomething()` is not Google Apps Script. I think that it's Javascript. I think that this is the reason of your issue. So when the following modification is done, I think that the script works.

  ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
      <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
      <br />
      <div id="status">Static</div>
      <br />
      <script>
      document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //    google.script.run.DoSomething();
        DoSomething();
      });
      function DoSomething() {
        var obj = document.getElementById("status");
        alert("kachow");
        obj.innerText = "It's magic!";    
      }
      </script>  
      </body>  
    </html>
  ```
- But I thought that you might want to communicate between Javascript side and Google Apps Script. So in this case, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

`Code.gs`：

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
         .setTitle('DynamicTest');
}

function DoSomething() {
  return "It's magic!";
}
```

`Index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
  <br />
  <div id="status">Static</div>
  <br />
  <script>
  document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(value => {
      var obj = document.getElementById("status");
      alert("kachow");
      obj.innerText = value;
    }).DoSomething();
  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: You're a **genius**! I was thinking about it convoluted. I had to twist around my logic a bit. Oh yeah for the record it was the latter code I was interested in with the communication. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Advanced question. Works great when I click the button I can process a function and when it's done I can notify the user with a new message that way. What if I wanted to display a "Processing..." message  while it's running the DoSomething function and change the Status when it's done.

Comment: Got it thanks!   I added _"var obj = document.getElementById('status');obj.innerText = 'Processing. Please wait...';"_ as the first execution statement before the withSuccessHandler   :-)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.